# Django Filter for Model function

Tags: python, django, search

I am trying to filter through a TextField where I have stripped it of its HTML tags. However, it gives me this error: "Cannot resolve keyword 'search' into field." Here is my code:

models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  body = models.TextField()
  
  def search_body(self):
    tags = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(tags, '', self.body)
    return cleantext
```

views.py

```
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Entry
...

def search_list(request, query=None):
  search = "search"
  entrys = Entry.objects.filter(status="publish").filter(Q(search_body__icontains=search)).distinct()
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the `search` in `search_body` that's the problem. Your field is only called `body`

Comment: Oops. I forgot to change the search in models.py back. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way to get what I'm aiming at.
All I have to do is to override the "save" function, as so:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_body = clean_text(self)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, at least not like this.

First, `search_body` would need defining as a `@property` becuase you want to treat it as one.

Mainly though, Django doesn't support filtering on properties because it would need to work out how to turn them into SQL.

You could look into: https://pypi.org/project/django-property-filter/

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to achieve.
If you want to clean the body of the entry before saving it to DB, you need to re-write save method.
If you are interested in search results, then you can search the body of the Entry and the result will be the same as searching the cleaned text.

The search function in the code below searches for the entries that have status='publish' and contain the word 'search' in their bodies. In both cases Django will return you the same QuerySet of Entry objects.

models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  body = models.TextField()
  
  @property
  def clean_text(self):
    tags = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(tags, '', self.body)
    return cleantext
```

views.py

```
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Entry
...

def search_list(request, query=None):
  search = "search"
  entrys = Entry.objects.filter(status="publish", body__icontains=search).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What I am trying to aim at with the code is this. If I make the body `<p></p>`, and search for "p," I don't want this entry to show up. So I am trying to filter through a body without the HTML tags.